# C++ STL stack question: Why does pop() not throw an exception if the stack is empty?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, stack

Why does std::stack::pop() not throw an exception if the stack is empty and there is nothing to pop?

(I'm designing a specialized Stack for my own code and would like to know the tradeoffs with this approach (which requires one to manually check if the stack is empty) vs. throwing an exception.

My guess here would be that although C++ supports exception-handling, it comes with a small runtime overhead, and therefore, for maximum performance, the decision was made not to throw an exception in std::stack::pop).

Comment: You guessed almost correctly.  It's not the overhead of exceptions that's the problem.  It's testing if the stack is empty every time.  If you use an std::stack, you are expected to know(or check yourself) when it becomes empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how checking for stack-empty before each pop would be inefficient. It would be a very small constant-time comparison to make, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Nocturne: It would be small, but it would still be something.  Something > Nothing.  That said, std::stack is a container adapter, so it just does whatever the underlying container does in this case.

Comment: @Fred: Actually come to think of it, most algorithms would probably be checking for empty stack anyway. So providing an IsEmpty() method and having pop throw an exception makes more sense to me (catching bugs and what not), and the issue of performance is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @Moron: To get that behavior you are free to use underlying containers which throw on pop_back when empty, but that's just not the behavior of the stdlib containers.

Comment: @Fred: Sure, but that was not the point :-) (context: OP is trying to design his own stack). What happens if you do a top on an empty std::stack? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: @Moron: It calls and returns underlying_container.back().  Back() is UB for empty stdlib containers.

Comment: @Fred: So in your code, you _will_ be calling the empty check before calling the top, right? So Something > Nothing is probably moot, isn't it? i.e. the argument of empty check being a performance hit is not really valid, isn't it? And it seems to me that most algorithms, like say dfs etc have the empty check built in... Also, it seems like std:stack _requires_/(recommends?) the empty check to be called before a top. Anyway...

Comment: @Moron: Not all algorithms need to check.  Depending on what is happening, you might be guaranteed by the rest of the algorithm that you never pop an empty stack.

Comment: @Fred: Of course, not arguing against that. Take dfs for instance! If you try to pop an empty stack, you are done :-) So you can perhaps deal with an exception there. In case of STL, the argument of performance is moot as you need to call empty check anyway. OP was looking for guidance whether his stack should have isEmpty or not and that decision should be driven by what the usage patterns would be. Trying to base in on what STL does or does not is actually asking the wrong question.

Comment: I wonder if similar conversations were had at some point when implementing `strcpy` vs `strncpy`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. The C++ standard always prefers performance to safety. But there may be STL implementations that include debug range checks.

Comment: And it's for this reason (efficiency) that STL requires you to call value_type& top() followed by void pop(), rather than having a pop() which returns by value.

Comment: @Nathan: Those are separated for exception safety. If the copy ctor throws while returning from a pop that returns by value, you've just leaked the item that was on top of the stack (i.e., the item is lost, and you can't restore it to the stack either). See: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm

Comment: @Jerry has it spot on! It has nothing to do with perf. In fact, forcing developers to call top before pop is worse in terms of performance...

Comment: @Jerry Ah, I didn't consider that - makes perfect sense! @Moron Is top/pop not more efficient if the elements in question are expensive to copy?

Comment: @Moron: Do you have evidence for that?

Comment: @GMan: Of course not :-) One of the cases we talk of does not even exist! Perhaps I should have included the word "probably". And I meant to include the check for empty stack in the previous comment too.

Comment: @Nathan: I don't see why pop _has_ to return by value. I meant to also include the check for empty stack in the previous comment (ok, repeated that).

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to return a pointer/ref to a deleted element. But I'm guessing you know that and you're questioning whether std::stack must strictly own its contained elements, and therefore whether pop() should be responsible for deallocating an element or simply updating a stack pointer...

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, that is it. For me, the reason to pop an element off the stack would be to be able to use it! It just does not _feel_ like the stack one learns about. Of course, having the container own the objects has its advantages.

Answer (score 19):

I would argue that the reason pop() doesn't have to throw an exception has *nothing* to do with efficiency or performance, but with - exceptions.

As is argued [elsewhere](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/10/why-does-stdstackpop-returns-void.html):

> 1. SGI explanation: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html
>      One might wonder why pop() returns
>      void, instead of value_type. That is,
>      why must one use top() and pop() to
>      examine and remove the top element,
>      instead of combining the two in a
>      single member function? In fact, there
>      is a good reason for this design. If
>      pop() returned the top element, it
>      would have to return by value rather
>      than by reference: return by reference
>      would create a dangling pointer.
>      Return by value, however, is
>      inefficient: it involves at least one
>      redundant copy constructor call. Since
>      it is impossible for pop() to return a
>      value in such a way as to be both
>      efficient and correct, it is more
>      sensible for it to return no value at
>      all and to require clients to use
>      top() to inspect the value at the top
>      of the stack.
> 2. std::stack < T > is a template. If pop() returned the top element, it
>      would have to return by value rather
>      than by reference as per the of above
>      explanation. That means, at the caller
>      side it must be copied in an another T
>      type of object. That involves a copy
>      constructor or copy assignment
>      operator call. What if this type T is
>      sophisticated enough and it throws an
>      exception during copy construction or
>      copy assignment? In that case, the
>      rvalue, i.e. the stack top (returned
>      by value) is simply lost and there is
>      no other way to retrieve it from the
>      stack as the stack's pop operation is
>      successfully completed!

Once we conclude that pop should *not* return the element it pops and thus its interface is fixed as `void pop()`, it - this being my opinion - doesn't make any sense anymore to prescribe what happens when pop() is called on an empty stack.

Note that the standard requires `!empty()`as precondition for calling pop().

UncleBens (in the comments) certainly has a point that not checking preconditions at runtime (which is never prescribed by the C++ std AFAIK) has a certain performance smell to it. However, to quote part of the original question: (emphasis mine)

> (I'm designing a specialized Stack for
>   my own code and would like to know the
>   tradeoffs with **this approach (which
>   requires one to manually check if the
>   stack is empty**) vs. throwing an
>   exception.

I will argue, that the fact that `pop()` doesn't return anything renders the question moot. It (IMHO) simply doesn't make sense to force pop() to validate if the stack is empty, when we really don't get anything back from it (i.e. if the stack would be empty pop() can simply be a noop, which is (admittedly) not prescribed by the Std either).

I think one can either ask why `top()` does not throw an exception *or* one can ask why `pop()` doesn't return the top element. If `pop` doesn't return anything, throwing an exception doesn't make sense (in the C++ world) -- Claiming that it doesn't throw an exception "because of the runtime costs of exceptions" like other answers seem to imply is - IMHO - missing the point.

Comment: Thanks, that was informative. Could you provide a link where I can access the C++ standard?

Comment: I fail to see, though, how choosing not to enforce preconditions at runtime has something to do with anything other than performance...

Comment: @UncleBens - I think the exception argument is the most compelling. It's impossible for `::std::stack::pop` to satisfy the strong exception guarantee if it returns the top element.

Comment: @Nocture: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/ -> http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf

Comment: I don't understand this argument. Whether or not a stack implementation checks whether the stack is empty before popping or not gives the difference between the program being in a valid state after the pop or not. Whether an exception is thrown and how expensive this is, isn't the main issue. The trade off is: is it worth the implementation checking whether it is valid to perform the pop or not. If the program is designed such that it is guaranteed to never pop from an empty stack the check is redundant and pure overhead. Other clients may never be sure and would have to make the check anyway.

Comment: @Charles : Note that the question asked "why does pop() not throw an exception" and *not* why does pop not check its preconditions. With the way std::stack is designed, one has to view `pop`and `top` together. And given a C++ mindset, it kind of becomes obvious that neither of them will check their preconditions. (Though in the case of `pop`it would be trivial for an implementation to make it a no-op in case of an empty stack.) Calling `pop` or `top` on an empty stack is simply UB, just as accessing an out-of-bounds index of a std::vector.

Comment: @Martin: I still don't understand how your orignal argument applies. The exception safety argument is an argument for `top()` and void `pop()` over `pop()` returning a value but for either interface you can choose to check pre-conditions and throw an exception or let _undefined behavior_ happen when you pop from an empty stack. Checking pre-conditions is a necessary precursor for throwing a meaningful exception so it is valid to consider the fact that pre-conditions don't have to be checked if the interface isn't going to guarantee to throw an exception when popping from an empty stack.

Comment: @Charles: pop() *is* allowed to check its preconditions and it *is* allowed to throw. Given its interface (returning void) I just think that it doesn't make sense to *specify* that it should throw one. If pop() were implemented to check whether the stack be empty, it should - IMHO - just ignore the call. (And we could get into a discussion if a failed precondition check should throw an exception  or should abort() or assert() ...)

Answer (score 6):

As almost all features in C++, they are designed around the concept that you don't pay for what you don't use. Not all environments support exceptions, traditionally, and most notably game development.

So forcing the use of exceptions if you use std::stack would be failing one of the design guidelines. You want to be able to use stack even if exceptions are disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth mentioning that `pop()` is *allowed* to throw if the stack is empty -- it's just not required to. In your stack, you could `assert` that the stack wasn't empty, and that would be perfectly fine (`pop` on an empty stack seems to give UB, so you can do pretty much whatever you want, really).

Comment: Where is it documented that pop() is allowed to throw? Does the spec specify this?

Comment: @Nocturne: §17.4.4.8/3: "Any other functions defined in the C++ Standard Library that do not have an exception-specification may throw implementation-defined exceptions unless otherwise specified." No exception specification is given for `std::stack::pop()`. It just invokes `pop_back`, which doesn't seem to have an exception specification either.

Comment: To me, I think the more important point is that `push_back()` is defined to perform `a.erase.(--a.end())` which is UB if `a.begin() == a.end()` and this is what allows "anything to happen". `erase` is normally guaranteed to throw nothing for `list` and nothing if the copy constructor or assignment operator of the contained type does not throw for `vector` and `deque`; these being the containers that you usually build a `stack` with.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Presumably you meant `pop` rather than `push_back`?

Comment: Oops, I meant `pop_back` being what `pop` calls.

Comment: +1: it is about programming-by-contract, API design and undefined behaviour. `pop()` has **undefined** behviour if the stack is empty. A related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390126/what-should-the-pop-method-return-when-the-stack-is-empty/7390181#7390181

Answer (score 1):

exceptions are optional, and the STL wants to be available everywhere.  think embedded systems: lots of C++ code, no exception support from runtimes.

Comment: So in an embedded system, vector::at() and new do not throw exceptions at all?

Comment: "lots of C++ code, no exception support from runtimes" Seems contradictory to me. C++ very clearly has exceptions, if your platform doesn't support it, you're not using C++, you're using an implementation-specific derivative of C++.

Answer (score 1):

Performance aside, I don't think popping from an empty stack is an exceptional scenario - therefore I would't throw there either.

Comment: I would argue that it is an exceptional scenario. Given that you would be checking for the empty stack anyway (most algorithms have this check built in), trying to pop an empty stack would be an exception.

Comment: +1 Thanks for being the voice of reason here. Exceptions just shouldn't be thrown in response to failed preconditions that the caller can (easily) check.