# Mixing C++ Containers with C language structs

Tags: c++

I have spent 2 days chasing an issue involving C++ container, `std::list`, and C-Style structs.  Is the following undefined behavior (Note the type for the `std::list` parameter)?

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Point_Struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

typedef struct Point_Struct Point;

int main()
{
  std::list<Point> line;
  Point p;
  p.x = 3;
  p.y = 10;
  line.push_back(p);

  cout << "Size of container: " << line.size() << "\n";

  //  Here's the issue:
  line.pop_back();

  //  The size should be zero.
  cout << "Size of container after pop_back(): " << line.size() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I ran this on Visual Studio 2017 and I get an exception error, 0xC0000005, (memory access) on the call to `pop_back`.

The exception is also thrown on any method that changes the ordering of the items in the `list`, such as assignment and `sort`.

If I change the type of `line` to `std::list<Point_Struct>`, there are no exceptions thrown.

*Note:  The issue was found in a larger program.  The code above illustrates the root cause of the issue:  `std::list<typedef struct>` vs. `std::list<struct>`*

*Note:  The exception is thrown in VS2017 debug mode but not in release mode.*

Sorry, but multiple questions follow:

1. Is there anything in standard C++ (11 or later) declaring undefined
   behavior for using a `typedef` instead of a `struct` as the template
   parameter for `std::list`?
2. Would this be a Visual Studio bug?

I haven't tried on G++ or other compilers.

**Edit 1: VS2017 version info**
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
Version 15.9.14
Installed product:  Visual C++ 2017 - 00369-60000-00001-AA071

**Compilation Info**
Configuration:  Debug
Platform: Win32
Warning Level: Level3 (/W3)
Optimization: Disabled (/Od)
Enable C++ Exception: Yes (/EHsc)
Basic Runtime Checks: Both (/RTC1)
Disable Language Extensions: No
Conformance mode: No

**Platform**
Platform:  Windows 7

Comment: Don't bother trying it on other toolchains. It will work. There's nothing fatal about that code (except, apparently, using VS2017 to build+run it). Not surprisingly, I also have no issue with this on VS2015u3. Curiosity is killing me. What happens when you use `using Point = struct Point_Struct;` It should be synonymous behavior (broken or not). Regardless, that smells like a bug if that code really does repro on your rig.

Comment: Also on MSVC 2019, 16.2.2 no problem in x86 or x64 debug

Comment: What compiler flags are you using, and which specific version of the compiler?

Comment: Before we get carried away, has anyone actually reproduced this with VS2017?

Comment: I added version details and compilation settings.

Comment: With [`std::stack`, this can be UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387995/10957435) if you're not careful. Maybe you're finding yourself in a similar situation?

Comment: @Chipster Nowhere does the code mention std::stack. Before people start coming up with daft theories like this could someone actually confirm that this can be reproduced with VS2017.

Comment: @Chipster:  The Original Author used `std::list`.  I would not change the container to `std::stack` because that changes the order of the items.  If any change, I would switch to `std::vector`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth No, but I'm saying that if the larger program tries to to something bad like pop from an empty list, it may be similar to the linked question.

Comment: @Chipster According to the OP, *this code* produces the stated problem. Specifically, *"I ran this on Visual Studio 2017 and I get an exception error"* . Therefore, no speculation of the larger problem is required. Frankly, I cannot see how this is *not* a tool chain defect. Either that or the OP's VS2017 install is polluted by lord-knows-what.

Comment: just ran in on this with no problems. Version 15.9.14
Installed product: Visual C++ 2017 - 00369-60000-00001-AA565

Comment: Suggest debugging side by side with another VS2017 on a clean install. Something appears specific to that installation. I hate when this happens and it's been a long time. But worth it to track down.

Comment: No Problems on VS2017 -  C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27032.1 using `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /EHsc /Foobj/list_point.cpp /Febin/list_point.cpp /Tp list_point.cpp` the output is as expected. (no warnings or errors)

Comment: I checked with VS Installer and there are no updates.

Comment: I had a VS update today. to 15.9.15. (of course I only boot W10 to answer questions like this -- so it could be from several days ago...)

Comment: If you want another data-point, it also compiles and runs fine using VS10 from the Win7_SDK as well with the same command line, e.g. extensions corrected from above, `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /EHsc /Foobj/list_point /Febin/list_point /Tp list_point.cpp` (they were informational output from a batch file I use that was using `%~1` instead of `%~n1` to output the object and executable filenames -- corrected)

Comment: This code works for me as well.  I could help diagnose this problem more deeply at an assembly language level, but it'd require you to send me the .exe and .obj files that got made from the above source code.  I would definitely try doing a clean build of this as well. (Also, is this x86 or x64?)

Answer (score -1):

I compiled and ran your code with g++ 11 in Eclipse (Ubuntu 18) and it worked perfectly,

Output:

```
Size of container: 1
Size of container after pop_back(): 0
```

Have you tried/is it possible to swap `typedef` for `using`? This might fix it:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Point_Struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

using Point = Point_Struct;

int main()
{
  std::list<Point> line;
  Point p;
  p.x = 3;
  p.y = 10;
  line.push_back(p);

  cout << "Size of container: " << line.size() << "\n";

  //  Here's the issue:
  line.pop_back();

  //  The size should be zero.
  cout << "Size of container after pop_back(): " << line.size() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is not a workaround.  Not using the `typedef` works with no exceptions (IMHO, is the proper coding style).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews unless you want to make an alias for any reason