# Reset an element in a circular buffer

Tags: arrays, c++11, circular-buffer, stdarray

I was asked to implement a circular buffer that takes **an unspecified type** in C++. I assume the generic type to be of **primitive type**. (or should it consider non-primitive types?) For the buffer, I am using a **basic array, e.g. T[]** with **new** and **delete** to initialize and destroy it.

I have implemented the buffer class and tested it on integers with the expected output. But it does not work on `std::string`. The problem is that, when I pop the buffer, I clear the element by setting it to zero, and the compiler complains that doing so is ambiguous. As such, I need a generic way to clear an element, and I thought the `std::array` might support this feature, but I cannot find it in the documentation.

Is there a generic way to clear an element in a std::array or basic array, or is std::allocator my only option? Or, if I am completely in the wrong direction, How should I implement the pop method to **reset the first element and increment the front index to that of the next element**?

Thanks in advance!

In case it helps, below is my related code:

```
template<class T> T CircularBuffer<T>::pop_front()
{
    if (_size == 0)
        return 0;
    T value = buffer[_front];
    buffer[_front] = 0;
    if (--_size == 0)
    {
        _front = -1;
        _back = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        _front = (_front + 1) % _capacity;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) should be used instead. And there are no reference types in C++. If you think `class` is a reference type and `struct` is a value type, then no that's not the case.

Comment: @Jagannath Thanks for pointing that out! I have reworded to **primitive** (what I meant by value type) and **non-primitive** (what I meant by reference type).

Comment: So, the  answer is to [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: You can assign `T()` to the element, or use placement new and explicit destructor calls. The latter is more correct; the former is easier to write.

Comment: @Jagannath I guess the OP wants the [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to be fixed size. So no deque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) you do not really *remove* elements from memory, otherwise as Jagannath pointed out [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is your option. You more like "reset" the elements that have been popped.

```
buffer[_front] = 0;
```

means "assign `0` to a `T`". There are two methods that do that for `T = std::string` which explains the ambiguity. A bit simplified they look like this:

```
std::string std::string::operator=(char c);

std::string std::string::operator=(const char *cPtr);
```

I guess you don't want any of this, so my choice would be (as T.C. wrote):

```
buffer[_front] = T();
```

Additionally (and for a very similar reason)

```
if (_size == 0)
    return 0;
```

is also a problem since it will crash, watch this:

```
std::string a = circularBuffer.pop_front(); // crashes on empty buffer
```

You *could* `return T()` here but the cleaner way would certainly be throwing an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Thank you! I actually meant to ask how to "reset"; I've edited the question. So `T()` can be applied on primitive types as well? As to the exception handling, I was convinced by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892108/c-stl-stack-question-why-does-pop-not-throw-an-exception-if-the-stack-is-em) and thought I would return nothing instead.

Comment: @ThomasHsieh I see, in case you want to save the time for an empty-check, you may consider removing the whole `if` statement.

Comment: @ThomasHsieh Please mark the answer that suits your needs as "accepted" by clicking the check (near vote count).

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this, is by treating the memory as raw memory, and using placement new, and manual destructor call.

It could look something like this:

```
void push(const T& val)
{
    new ( data + sizeof(T)*idx++ ) T { val };
}

void pop()
{
    ( (T*) (data + sizeof(T)*--idx) ) -> ~T();
}
```

Comment: Reading the question I think `pop()` should return a `T`, a copy of the one that is about to be destroyed.